# How to identify the python, pip and installed modules location on linux?

Tags: linux, python, pip

I started learning python but I am finding it difficult to understand on linux.

```
uname -a
Linux machine-name 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

which python
/usr/local/bin/python

which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

pip --version
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

python
Python 2.7.16 (default, May  6 2020, 13:05:58) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import urllib2
>>> os.path.abspath(urllib2.__file__)
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.pyc'

pip install requests
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a release (2.7.7+) that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.PersistentlyDeprecated2018,
Requirement already satisfied: requests in ./dist-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in ./dist-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in ./dist-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in ./dist-packages (from requests) (2020.4.5.1)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in ./dist-packages (from requests) (1.25.9)

Python 2.7.16 (default, May  6 2020, 13:05:58) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> import requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named requests
>>>
```

`pip install requests`, says as installed. But when checked in interactive mode, errors out as no module name requests. Can you please help me to understand from which locations these modules are being used (where this path has been set ?) and how to install modules at that particular location ?

Can you please help me ?

Comment: Are you sure you wouldn't rather start with `python3`?

Comment: @Panki : Currently no Python3. Would need to continue on existing.

Comment: Can you try installing with `python -m pip install requests` ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your pip version doesn't install packages for your python version. (as in pip3 and python 2.7). If you want to force pip to use python3 (or python 2.7), install your modules using `pythonx.x -m pip install <module name>`, where x.x is your desired python version